# List implementation not resolving casts

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I made my own array based list implementation and its not restricting invalid arguments. If I create with a cast, `MyList<String> myList = new MyList<String>()`, it will still accept all other arguments (int, float, double, etc). How can I fix this so if a data type is specified thats all that will be accepted; if a datatype is not specified then I want it to work as it it now.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyList <T> implements MyListInterface
{

    private Object[] contents;
    private int size;

    public MyList()
    {
        this(10);
    }

    public MyList(int length)
    {
        contents = new Object[length];
        size = 0;
    }

    private void alterArraySize(int value)
    {
        int len = 0;

        //Value is 1 shrink array; value is 2 then double it
        switch (value)
        {
            case 1:
                len = contents.length / 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                len = contents.length * 2;
                break;
        }

        Object[] copyArr = new Object[len];

        //Copy array
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            copyArr[i] = contents[i];
        }

        contents = copyArr;
    }

    public <T> boolean insertHead(T newEntry)
    {

        size++;

        if ((size + 1) == contents.length)
            alterArraySize(2);

        //Shift elements up one
        for (int i = size; i >= 0; i--)
            contents[i + 1] = contents[i];

        contents[0] = newEntry;

        return true;
    }


    public <T> boolean insertTail(T newEntry)
    {
        //If the number of items in the list
        if ((size + 1) == contents.length)
            alterArraySize(2);

        //Put the newEntry in the last slot in the array
        contents[size++] = newEntry;

        return true;
    }

    public <T> Object deleteHead()
    {
        //Set temp to first item in the array
        Object temp = contents[0];

        //Delete the first item
        contents[0] = null;

        //Shift all items in the list down one position
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            contents[i - 1] = contents[i];
        }

        //Update size to accommodate for the item deletion
        size--;
        return temp;
    }


    public <T> Object deleteTail()
    {
        //Set temp to last item in array
        Object temp = contents[--size];

        //Delete the last item
        contents[size] = null;

        //Resize if the number of items in the list is half the length
        if (size <= contents.length / 2)
            alterArraySize(1);

        return temp;
    }


    public void display()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            System.out.println(contents[i]);
    }


    public <T> int contains(T anEntry)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (contents[i].equals(anEntry))
                return ++i;
        }

        return 0;
    }


    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return size == 0;
    }


    public boolean isFull()
    {
        //List can't be full
        return size == contents.length;
    }

    public <T> Object get(int givenPosition)
    {
        if ((givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= size))
            return contents[givenPosition - 1];

        return null;
    }

    public <T> void set(T s, int givenPosition)
    {
        contents[givenPosition - 1] = s;
    }

    public <T> Object remove(int givenPosition)
    {
        Object temp = null;

        //Check if givenPosition is valid and shift elements after remove
        if ((givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= size))
        {
            temp = contents[givenPosition - 1];
            for (int i = givenPosition; i < size; i++)
            {
                contents[i - 1] = contents[i];
            }

            contents[size--] = null;
        }

        return temp;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return size;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of your methods are themselves generic. So, they have their own type parameter, that have nothing to do with the one declared with your class. The below method declaration is generic:

```
public <T> boolean insertHead(T newEntry)
```

So, whatever parameterized instance of the class you create, the method will accept any argument type, and type `T` for this method will be inferred as that type. To solve the issue, you should remove `<T>` part from every method. Change for example, above method to:

```
public boolean insertHead(T newEntry)
```

Also, your methods should have a return type of `T` instead of `Object`, else that would fail at the caller end. Change the method:

```
public <T> Object get(int givenPosition)
{
    if ((givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= size))
        return contents[givenPosition - 1];

    return null;
}
```

to:

```
public T get(int givenPosition)
{
    if ((givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= size))
        return (T) contents[givenPosition - 1];  // Add cast

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. So does this mean that the class accepts generics since its in the class definition? And since every class inherits from type object it will just resolve to whatever class is passed as a cast, otherwise its generic because of the <T> in the class definition.

Comment: @Whoppa What do you mean by - "Every class inherits from type object?*. Yes the class is generic, because of `<T>` following the class name .

Comment: I was under the impression that every class is derived from type object. Like String inherits from type object the same as Node inherits from object. Am I wrong in my thinking?

Comment: @Whoppa Oh. I misinterpreted as "type" object. You meant to say class `Object`. yes that is true.

Comment: @Whoppa Yes, everything inherits from `Object`, but it's not clear what inference you're trying to draw from that. In particular, `List<String>` is *not* a subtype of `List<Object>`.

Comment: @chrylis Just that my methods with a return type of Object will work when there are primitives in the list. Would primitives be autoboxed if passed?

Comment: @Whoppa First of all, your methods shouldn't have a return type of `Object`, rather that should be `T`. Add appropriate cast while returning from method to `T`. And yes, passing primitives will be autoboxed to respective wrappers.

Comment: What do you mean it will fail at the caller end? It was working as type object, what makes a generic type better than object?

Comment: @Whoppa If the return type of your method is `Object`. And then you call `get()` method for `MyList<String>`, you would expect it to return a `String`, and store the return value in `String` reference. That is where it will give you compiler error. Try it.

Comment: Oh yes I see! It does indeed give a compiler error. Thanks for the extra help!